# ReactJS: JSON/Service Data is not loading along with page reload with react-router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-thunk, react-router-redux

In my react application I am using `react-router` to navigate between pages. When I clicked on the links the page will display first time. However when I used to refresh the page , It was showing `Cannot /Get pageName` error, I resolved this issue by adding `historyApiFallBack: true` in `webpack.config.js` file. However I am not seeing the data in reloaded page. I mean the data from service or static json object is not rendering from `redux` to `react`. For ex: It displays the page but the select boxes doesn't contain options (options were 
coming from some service json object).

Routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';
import App from './components/App';
import ViewPage from './components/ViewPage';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage';
import CreatePage from './components/CreatePage';

export default (
<Route path="/" component={App}>
<IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
<Route path="viewpage" component={ViewPage} />
<Route path="createpage" component={CreatePage} />
</Route>

);
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import routes from './routes';

export const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
<Router history={history} routes= {routes} /> 
</Provider>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

ConfigureStore.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export default function configureStore(initialState){
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );
}
```

Please suggest ...

Thanks,
Shash

Comment: Looks like code snippets aren't related to "some service json object". Please be sure you have correct flow for that json.

Comment: The above code snippets are for routing issue , none of the data is not displaying on the page. when we refresh routed page (http://localhost:3000/viewpage).